# C# Windows Form App CRUD Not Updating Record

Tags: c#, crud

I'm trying to make a CRUD application in C# to keep track of projects, who is assigned to them, and their status. I am making good progress but I cannot get the "Update" function to work. Whenever I try to update a record, I get my own error message instead of "Updated successfully".

Anyone know what's causing my if statement to not execute properly?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;


namespace SFTool
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("my connection string here");

        public int ProjectID;

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // load in sql data to the data grid view
            GetProjectsDataset();
        }

        private void GetProjectsDataset()
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sfProjects", con);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(sdr);
            con.Close();

            dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void insertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // allow user to insert data into the database, or create new records
            if (IsValid())
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO sfProjects VALUES (@Project_ID, @FirstName, @LastName, @Project_Status)", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_ID", projectIDTextbox.Text); // maps @Project_ID to the project ID textbox
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstNameTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastNameTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_Status", projectStatusTextbox.Text);

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("New record has been successfully added to the database", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                // now update/REFRESH the database so it shows the new record
                GetProjectsDataset();

                // reset form controls
                ResetFormControls();
            }
        }

        // data validation. (Make sure project id is never empty)
        private bool IsValid()
        {
            if (projectIDTextbox.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Project ID is required.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return false;
            }

            // else return true (it is valid)
            return true;
        }

        private void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // resets, or clears, the textboxes 
            ResetFormControls();
        }

        private void ResetFormControls()
        {
            projectIDTextbox.Clear();
            firstNameTextBox.Clear();
            lastNameTextBox.Clear();
            projectStatusTextbox.Clear();

            projectIDTextbox.Focus();
        }

        private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            // WHen you click on a row in the data grid, the textboxes will automatically populate with that rows values

            ProjectID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value);

            projectIDTextbox.Text = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            firstNameTextBox.Text = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            lastNameTextBox.Text = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            projectStatusTextbox.Text = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        }

        private void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ProjectID > 0)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE sfProjects SET (Project_ID = @Project_ID, FirstName = @FirstName, LastName = @LastName, Project_Status = @Project_Status WHERE ProjectID = @Project_ID)", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_ID", projectIDTextbox.Text); // maps @Project_ID to the project ID textbox
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstNameTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastNameTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_Status", projectStatusTextbox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_ID", this.ProjectID);

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Record is successfully updated", "Updated", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                // now update/REFRESH the database so it shows the new record
                GetProjectsDataset();

                // reset form controls
                ResetFormControls();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a record to update", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I finally figured out that

```
                ProjectID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value);
```

Needs to be

```
                ProjectID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
```

Comment: Please use the "visual-studio" tag only for questions regarding the development environment itself.

Comment: Are you sure the `dataGridView_CellClick` event is triggering? If so, are you sure `ProjectID` is being set to what you expect? By the time you click `updateButton`, `ProjectID` must be `<= 0` for your error to be displayed. I only see it being set in the `dataGridView_CellClick` event, so you could set a breakpoint in that method and see what the debugger tells you.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson I added a textbox to see what the value of ProjectID is, turns out that it is always 0. I'm positive my CellClick function is working because all of the other textboxes get filled when I click a row in the datagridview. I am struggling to find why the ProjectID is 0 and why it doesn't get assigned the ProjectID of the row I am selecting

Comment: Your life would be so much easier if you'd use strongly typed bound datatables. All that code you've written there, can be written with a mouse in about 15 clicks